# CMake Windows Phone problems

Tags: windows-phone, cmake

I have a project that is using CMake as a build system, and I need to port it to Windows Phone. Sadly, but when I try to run `cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 12 2013"` it fails, saying

```
 A Windows Phone component with CMake requires both the Windows Desktop SDK
 as well as the Windows Phone '8.0' SDK.  Please make sure that you have
 both installed
```

And this is really weird, because I do have both of them installed. Adding `-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` and `-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION` doesn't help, still the same result. Even if I specify the system version to 8.1, it still says I'm missing '8.0' SDK.

I tried googling, but it didn't help either. It seems that some people have run into same problem, but similar questions are all unanswered for some reason. I'm using CMake 3.2.2 now, tried on 3.2.0 with same output.

Completely lost at this now and have no idea what to do with that. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you open the project with cmake-gui, do you see any path variable you could maybe set?

Comment: @Antonio I already figured out the problem - it's CMake itself. It just looks for wrong directories in windows registry, so I rewrote it and will send the path to CMake team soon.

Comment: Cool! It would be nice if you could post a (brief) answer to your own question.

Comment: @Antonio I will just as soon as I fork CMake and apply a patch to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its been fixed in CMake 3.4 https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=15662

The location in the registry CMake uses to find the SDK's seem to have changed in Windows 10.